# Can I re-use code in a partial in Razor (Umbraco 8)?

Tags: razor, view, umbraco, embed

I have multiple partial views with markup. For styling the markup of these views I have several properties like color, background image etc. that can be set in Umbraco.

I would like to create a single piece of code that handles all styling, and can be used in all partial views (the variables should be available in the 'parent' view).

How can I add or embed this piece code to the views? I don't want to copypaste the code to each view because of maintainability.

Preferably, I want the code to be in a Razor view, not in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post about this for skrift last year.

https://skrift.io/issues/there-s-more-than-one-way-to-cook-an-egg/

I think you will want to use option 3

Kind regards

Paul